# How to access a <p> inside three layers of <div> using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, web-frontend

I'm trying to use Javascript so that a paragraph will alternate between two texts when the user presses a button on the webpage. The problem is that the `<p>` element I'm trying to manipulate lies within a `<div>` within a `<div>` within a `<div>`.

A low-level mockup of my code can be seen below:

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <div id="div3">
      <p>text1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All solutions I've found only state what to do if the `<p>` is within one `<div>`; solutions which have not worked for me.

Here's my latest attempt:

```js
function translate() {
  var x = document.getElementById("div1").getElementById("div2").getElementById("div3").getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
  if (x.innerHTML === "text1") {
    x.innerHTML = "text2";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "text1";
  }
}
```

How would I get this to work?

Edit: Nothing seems to be working so far. The `<div>` element all have classes, but that shouldn't affect things, right?

Edit2: My apologies for taking up your time, but I've found the issue was something else entirely. I'd been using a reserved word for my function call this whole time and had somehow never noticed that that was the issue instead. Thanks again to those who answered, and I shall look deeper at my code before posting my next question.

Comment: Use the descendant (*not* "child") selector

Comment: An ID is *unique*  - it makes no sense to stack 3 IDs in your javascript selector,  one is enough...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
var x = document.getElementById("div3")
```

If accessing by the Id directly, it does not really matter what the other DIVs are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.querySelectorAll to get an array of all p tags on the page.

```
const pTags = document.querySelectorAll('p')

pTags.forEach((p, i) => {
  if(i % 2 === 0) {
    p.innerHTML = 'text1'
  } else {
    p.innerHTML = 'text2'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If divs are always in that order, you can do it like this:

```js
var x = document.querySelector('#div1 #div2 #div3 p');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Ids, you can be more specific & try the following:

```
var x = document.querySelector('div > div > div > p')
```

This will be a very strict implementation & follows the condition without the ids or classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) in order to use the CSS selector `#div3 p` which means "pick up the paragraph element that is inside the element that has a `div3` id".

Then, as you're just changing a string of text, change either the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of that element, or its [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) (there are [subtle differences](https://openjavascript.info/2021/09/14/whats-the-difference-between-innertext-and-textcontent/) between them.)

```js
const para = document.querySelector('#div3 p');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', translate);

function translate() {
  if (para.textContent === 'text1') {
    para.textContent = 'text2';
  } else {
    para.textContent = 'text1';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <div id="div3">
      <p>text1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button">Translate</button>
```